# Find user name and User SID in active directory for Mac user in Objective-c Code

Tags: objective-c

I am new to Mac Development.
I am using Objective-C, and I want to know how to find the domain name and User SID for the user logged in to the Mac machine.
In Windows we have APIS provided by Microsoft whcih will tell us the user infromation from Active Directory. I am searching for a similar option for Mac development.

I want to know one more thing. In Mac we can get the user's ID using getuid( void ) function. But will it be unique for all domain users?. If it is not,then please tell me any altenative to look into so that I can maintain a unique ID for differentiating all users in domain.

Note: Here I am considering all Mac machines are connected to Windows Active Directory.Please guide me on this.

Thanks,
Tausif.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using the [membership API](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man3/mbr_uuid_to_sid.3.html) from BSD, you can query the domain controller for a user's SID

```
- (NSText*)getSidForUser:(NSText*)user
{
    uuid_t uuid;

    // change the type (ID_TYPE_USERNAME) for different types of data, such as Group
    if(mbr_identifier_to_uuid(ID_TYPE_USERNAME, [user UTF8String], [user length], uuid) != 0)
    {
        // handle error
        return nil;
    }

    nt_sid_t ntSid;
    if(mbr_uuid_to_sid(uuid, &ntSid) != 0)
    {
        // handle error
        return nil;
    }        

    char buffer[200] = {0};
    if(mbr_sid_to_string(&ntSid, buffer) != 0)
    {   
        // handle error     
        return nil;
    }

    NSString* sid = [NSString stringWithCString:buffer encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

    return sid;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

For the user name, you can use:

```
NSString * NSUserName( void );
NSString * NSFullUserName( void );
```

From `<Foundation/Foundation.h>`

For the user ID, simply use:

```
uid_t getuid( void );
```

From `<unistd.h>`

Comment: Hi Sir,Please consider me as beginner in MAC development. I am able to find the UID of the logged in user, but will it be unique for the all users in one domain. Consider I have few users which are in single domain, so this UID will be unique for all users in the domain? In windows we have SID (security identifier) which will be a unique ID for the user in active directory. Here the reason of my question is, that I want to know what will happen if mac machine is connected to windows active directory? Please guide me on this.

Comment: A uid is unique only for the current system and potentially only for the current session (if the system is using some form of dynamic accounts, for instance.)

Comment: So in that case can you please help me to find out alternative for maintaining unique identity within all users of the domain. Thanks, Tausif.